# Connecting Database asp.net VS 2013

Tags: asp.net

Hi I work on Visual Studio 2013. Firstly I tell you about steps which I made before I describe problem:
1. I create new project: ASP.NET Web Application ->Empty, named “DateBaseTraining” 
2. I added to my project New Item->Web Form, named “Default.aspx”
3. I added to my project ASP.NET folder->App_Data
4. I copied file named “Products.sdf” from my hard drive to folder App_Data 
5. I added to Default.aspx DropDownList from Toolbox.
6. I edited option of DropDownList  named “Choose Data Source..”
7. In “Select a data source” I chase New data source… 
8.Then window “Data Source Configuration Wizard” suddenly appeared and from list named “Where will application get data from” I chase SQL Database. In the textbox below text “Specify an ID for data source:” I wrote: CategoriesSql. I clicked OK.
9.Window named “Configure Data Source – CategoriesSql” suddenly appeared
**PROBLEM:** When I click on list below text “Which data connection should your application use to connect to the database?” THE LIST IS EMPTY!! CAN SOMEONE TELL MY WHY ITS EMPTY? On the list should be position “Products.sdf” to choose but there isn’t..
I don’t know why. I tried to do all the steps on second computer, on Visual Studio 2012 and it works well.  CAN SOMEONE CAN TELL ME HOW TO FIX THIS PROBLEM? I WANT TO SEE position “Products.sdf” to choose on list below text “Which data connection..”

Here is Prt Sc from my computer showing all steps I wrote: 
http://zapodaj.net/images/2d2bd1a0bd66f.jpg

Link to file Products.sdf:
http://www.speedyshare.com/avqHb/Products.sdf

Comment: We cannot help you with something that is not here. Post the code, **in the question**. Not on an external link

Comment: Using all caps in your question may not be a good idea. People tend to view that as the online equivalent of shouting. You can do *italicized text* `*italicized text*` or **bold text** `**bold text**` if you need to emphasize a certain point, but I wouldn't overuse those either.

Comment: @ ArtOfCode My problem is not about a code.. I give you a link to image to better understand whats going on, in my problem.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I need 10p reputation to post images

Comment: @Martin if it's not about code it's off topic. Period,